# Robot Framework Keyword for Connecting and disconnecting internet

Tags: selenium, robotframework, webautomation

Has anyone here used a robot framework for web automation to execute a test case involving connect and disconnect to the internet?

I have used appium for mobile, but not sure how to do this on the web.
I am using selenium Library and it's a web automation.

Comment: Anything you can do in python, you can do with robot framework. Have you looked into how to turn the wifi on and off via python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure with robot framework but you can try with python instead.

import subprocess

***to disconnect***

result = subprocess.run(["netsh", "interface", "set", "interface", "Wi-Fi", "DISABLED"])

print(result.returncode)

***to connect***

result = subprocess.run(["netsh", "interface", "set", "interface", "Wi-Fi", "ENABLED"])

print(result.returncode)